# Memory leakage in java service ( tomcat ) on AWS EC2 C3 series instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have facing high memory usage issue with web server application which running withtomcat service on EC2[ Type;- c3.8xlarge, OS-amazonlinux1 ]
allocated heap size- 40GB out of 64 GB for (c3.8xlarge) but it consuming gradually memory up to 100% in couple of hours then application get stopped.
this problem is happening from 27 DEC 2018 8.30 AM (IST). Before this application working smoothly.

Tested same application on r5 and m4, m5 series instance types. there memory consumption is optimal value with same heap size allocation [40gb out of 64gb] . Means application working without any issue.

we are tried to get some more details of any hardware changes on AWS infra for C3 series but not get any response .
may I wanna know project runs on C3 series facing same issue...?

Comment: Typical guess: There might patch update for memory pool of C3 series

Comment: Confirm 27 DEC 2018? Or was it 2019?

Comment: What consumes memory on this instance? Is it your application, web server, or something else?

Comment: memory consumed by application ruining with java process (tomcat)

Comment: Correct date 28 Dec 2019